# Where does the 12 come from in the denominator of the variance formula in the Wilcoxon (Mann-Whitney U) test?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I'm curious where this 12 comes from.

[image: Wilcoxon]